# Go to the last wrapped line with G

Tags: cursor-movement, wrapping

In Vim pressing `G` takes you to the last physical line. But, if the last line is wrapped around `G` puts the cursor on the first wrapped line in that last line, not the last wrapped line.

So, is there a way to get to the last wrapped line when pressing `G` without me having to press `j` or `gj` a bunch of times?

Comment: What about `G$`? What's it for anyway?

Comment: That's the one I am thinking about too but that puts me at the end of the last line. But, I would like it to be at the beginning of the last line.

Comment: Damn, I just realized there is `g0` all along. I feel really stupid for not being able to put that together.

Comment: Just add it as answer with explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple solutions.

1. You could use `G$g0`, like it was suggested in the comments. For example

   ```
   nnoremap G G$g0
   xnoremap G G$g0
   ```

   You don't really need to provide an `omap` since G is a line based movement, not a character-based movement. **Explanation**: `G` Moves to the last line, and `$` moves to the end of that line. Then `g0` moves to the beginning of that visual line, e.g. the first column of the last wrap.
2. This is admittedly a pretty strange solution, but you could use a recursive macro. This is essentially the same thing as hitting `gj` a bunch of times, except that it is only one keystroke and it happens faster. For example:

   ```
   nnoremap G :let @g='gj@q'<cr>@g
   xnoremap G :<C-u>let @g='gj@q'<cr>@g
   ```

   As a side note, this will not move you to the first column, but the same column. You could always add `g0` to the end, e.g.

   ```
   nnoremap G :let @g='gj@q'<cr>@gg0
   xnoremap G :<C-u>let @g='gj@q'<cr>@gg0
   ```

I recommend going with the first option.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I realized I could use `g0`  after I posting the question. The second one seems rather tricky. Why is it faster?

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop Sorry, my wording could have been better. I meant it is faster than hitting `gj` a bunch of times.